# Error checking if column value is empty or null

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to check if the column value`["CellNumber"]` is emtpy or not with if condition. Even if the column cell value is not empty, it is prompting with message box instead of exit the `foreach loop` and updating the data.

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Measurement", con);
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value) == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter cellnumber", "Missing Information");
                return;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            da.Update(ds, "Measurement");
        }
        catch (DBConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: It is not checking whether column already has a value or not. If the column["CellNumber"] already has a value and if I edit the column next to it called column["LastName"] then it is still asking to enter cell number in messagebox. It is in the same row and I think I need to get row index as well, but how ?

Comment: I tried the way gzaxx mentioned below `if (row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value.ToString()))
{
   //rest
}`

Comment: then try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14774551/1080742) `:D`

Answer (score 1):

Please check your number of rows in datagridview by doing

```
 DataGridView. If myDataGridView.Rows.Count == 0
```

If it is equal to 0 then it is empty

Answer (score 0):

you use the String "CellNumber", shouldn't it be an `int`?

`if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value) == "")`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value))
{ Your Code  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
if (row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value.ToString()))
{
   //rest
}
```

---

call `dgv.CurrentRow.DataGridView.EndEdit();` to save changes in all cells before validating :)

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgv.CurrentRow.DataGridView.EndEdit();
    dgv.EndEdit();
    ....
```

Comment: +1 actually it is enough `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value.ToString()))`

Comment: It is not, if `row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value` is null then calling `.ToString()` on it will throw an exception.

Comment: so, how about `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Cells["CellNumber"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))`? without the `row.Cells["CellNumber"].Value == null`?

Comment: You can't do that, parameter has to be `string`. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx)

Comment: This is not the right way, `EditedFormattedValue` should be used for accessing `dirty` values :)

Comment: what if i use the `EditedFormattedValue.ToString()` can you give me or your reference for the bad performance?

Comment: It is not checking whether column already has a value or not. If the column["CellNumber"] already has a value and if I edit the column next to it called column["LastName"] then it is still asking to enter cell number in messagebox. It is in the same row

Comment: Look at my comment and check if it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `.EditedFormattedValue`

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(row.Cells["CellNumber"].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter cellnumber", "Missing Information");
            return;
        }
```